# In story, how did Clark destroy the truck in Man of Steel without being caught?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

On January 12, 2012, we received one of our first glimpses of an intriguing visual from the set of Man of Steel.

[image]

It was one of the first released materials and likely earlier in production.  In the film, the final scene looks like this:

[image]

Could you walk me through the sequence of events from where Clark, in the heat of the moment, decides to vent his frustrations on this truck, where the end result is as we see it AND Clark does not get caught in the process?

Some additional presumptions:

- Clark cannot fly yet.
- Clark likely does not have Flash-like super speed.
- Some unknown amount of time passes from when Clark leaves the bar (daylight) and when the trucker sees his truck (night), however, they are close to Ellesmere Island in the far north latitudes.
- No one coming to or leaving the bar in the meantime said anything about the truck, so it likely did not arrive at that state until shortly before the trucker leaves.
- Ludlow (the trucker) is surprised by the truck so it appears no one heard a commotion outside.
- Based on the direction of the frayed bark, it appears the logs were driven through the truck from above rather than impaled upon the logs.

So in sum:

1. What sequence of events would allow Clark, with his power set at the time, produce this bit of abstract art?
2. How was it accomplished in a relatively short amount of time without the denizens of Cassidy's Roadhouse hearing the commotion or passing truckers seeing the event?

Comment: The fact that no one saw it could be explained by the fact that the bar is in the middle of nowhere. It's possible that the trucker was the next person to leave after Clark, having grown dark in the intervening time (1-2 hours later). As for not hearing it... I dunno.

Comment: Can he leap higher than a tall building at this point?

Comment: There is a problem with those assumptions: Clark **does** have super-speed. Even if not Flash-like, (combined with other super-habilities like super-strengh, x-rays and heatvision) enough to trash that truck undetected in less than a minute. The level of noise of the bar would mask the noise from the destruction, and the bar can be in an isolated area, so indeed there are not enough visitors to notice the state of the truck (or tell about it) before the driver.

Comment: If he's strong enough to drive logs into the ground and impale a truck on them, then he's strong enough to move his relatively light body quickly.

Comment: We don't actually see anything that indicates Clark has super-speed until he gets flight.  For example, when stealth is paramount at the Ellesmere military base, Clark does not use super speed to avoid detection.  He never quite does anything like Faora in Smallville.  However, even allowing for speed, the din of the bar we observed would not have covered the catastrophic sounds of impaled metal or destroyed asphalt.

Comment: From the flashback scene involving J. Kent and the tornado, I think is fair to assume he has the speed ability (although he does not use it then). Strength and speed are something your body develops when growing, and he would be aware of his limits. There is also hint that he might be a fast swimmer, from the scene of the gas platform. The ability to fly (whoever he does it), might require more training and awareness.  And I do think that the noise could have been either not that _catastrophically_ loud or indistinguishable of other noises there.

Comment: I would say that, even if the trucker inside heard a lot of noise outside, he would have been as surprised as if he had heard nothing...

Comment: Reminds me of the [Real story of Action Comics #1](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qz-rIUd2Fks/UqSgoh-X4JI/AAAAAAAACqY/Gfag0a6YP3Q/s1600/Action_Page.jpg) by [Kerry Callen](http://kerrycallen.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/superman-and-car.html)!

Comment: @manofsteelanswers.com - You seem to be overestimating the situational awareness of people who binge drink in seedy bars in the middle of the day.  This is even more true in light of the fact that many of these daylight binge drinkers are supposed to be driving trucks, which would ideally require that they be sober.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Cool question - I can maybe help fill in some details.

Having witnessed the filming of this scene, (super fun!), I'd say you've nailed it with: ***"...Clark knows that the singer, played by Allison Crowe, has a particularly deafeningly loud part of her act, and coordinates his actions with this aural camouflage."***

I serve as manager to Allison, the Canadian musician performing in Cassidy's Roadhouse. It's not seen in the released version of "Man of Steel", but after Clark's altercation with Ludlow, the barman Weaver (played by the terrific Howard Siegel) yells out from behind the taps:

> "You're fired, kid!"

This propels Clark into his act of mischief. Exiting the back door of the bar, with Ludlow bouncing an empty can off him... he's then in the parking area that's behind the building off the highway.

Allison resumes her musical performance, and, indeed, things gets really rocking. The denizens inside Cassidy's are raucous, and this provides plenty of cover for Clark to prepare his surprise for Ludlow - who's enjoying his fill of brewskies before venturing out again to his truck.

Comment: Love the behind-the-scene insight!  The "fired" line concurs with the novelization.  A picked up performance is the missing piece we needed, thanks.

Comment: Glad I can fill in a bit. There's a lot going on in that scene - and it was edited down to something very brief. The more "real time" action makes the elevated truck sequence fit naturally in this context. And Weaver was great - the "fired" line really punctuated things. Very tense emotions in the bar.

Comment: p.s. it's, either, "You're fired, kid!" or "Kid, you're fired!" that is yelled at Clark - dramatically capping the altercation, and then propelling things into the truck devastation out back, and the reveling inside, of Cassidy's

Answer (score 3):

The best I can come up with has a disturbing amount of premeditation.  Clark hijacks the truck, drives it to nearby seclusion, performs a complicated juggling act to get the truck just about as we see it, then drags his masterpiece back to the Roadhouse, and then for artistic effect ensures the cargo is strewn about, while using his super-hearing and x-ray vision to ensure he isn't disturbed.

Alternatively, Clark knows that the singer, played by Allison Crowe, has a particularly deafeningly loud part of her act, and coordinates his actions with this aural camouflage.

Is there a better in-continuity, diegetic explanation?

Comment: This could have been added to your question as a theory, instead of posted as it's own answer.

Comment: Well, this is highly unlikely.

Comment: That's sort of the point of the first "answer", it attempts to exclude the possibility that the act occurred elsewhere and then was brought back to the Roadhouse.  Therefore, a more likely answer should have occurred in the parking lot.

Comment: I still don't think it makes sense to assume that people who get wasted at lunchtime (when they should be driving trucks) are particularly likely to notice what is going on around them.  As a former alcoholic, I can assure you that, when I was a lush, a meteor could have landed in my bed and I wouldn't have noticed or cared, as long as I didn't run out of booze.  :)

Answer (score -1):

While analyzing the crime scene, these are my conclusions:

1. The towing section with the wooden logs was hit first from below folding the platform 2 meters before the half on a 60 degrees angle.
2. Some wooden logs fell. Then the truck cab was lifted from the bumper to the current height. 2 wooden logs were embedded from below with speed & strength in a way the whole structure had balance.

Conclusions: Regarding the mysterious finding in such location (Cassidy Inn Pub, 2954 Trans Canada Hwy 2, over on the East coast of Vancouver Island in Nanaimo) in that season, we may be facing the works of a giant, a yeti, a bigfoot, a sasquatch, or just a metahuman.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In order for an answer to be well-received here though, it should cite some evidence from an official source to back its conclusion/s up, rather than just asserting one or more conclusions and leaving it at that.